# Is SCP-173 just as vulnerable as normal concrete, or less?

Tags: scp-foundation

[SCP-173](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-173) is a construct that appears to be made of concrete, and doesn't move if it is being looked at (reminiscent of Weeping Angels).

Here's an image for those who don't want to sleep:

[image: SCP-173]

My question is, is this creature as vulnerable to explosives as concrete? Or is supernaturally tough?

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt there is a valid answer available.  The SCP entries gain a lot of their entertainment value from the fact that they AREN'T fully explained.  SCP 173 was the first, and has never been explained; it's not meant to make sense, it's meant to be CREEPY.  Rationality is included only to help suspension of disbelief.  SCP == Secure, Contain, Protect -- investigation occurs, too, but it no the primary focus; these things are often too dangerous.

Comment: Generally speaking, experiments are conducted when possible to attempt to neutralize or destroy the most dangerous SCPs. If it were as simple as dropping it into an industrial rock crusher, or using high explosives, or cutting it into pieces with a concrete saw and jackhammer, this would likely have happened a long time ago.

Comment: @JohnO The SCP Foundation does sometimes attempt to neutralize dangerous SCPs, but it does not do so as a rule. From SCP-1609: "This is why we have Special Containment Procedures instead of Special Destruction Procedures. If you break something, it's broken forever. When you try to destroy an anomaly, you can't take back your mistakes. That's what SCP-1609 has to tell us. This is why we're right and the GOC is wrong, people."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other users have stated, it's true that most SCP articles won't have sufficient canon to answer hardly any additional questions (which is sort of the point of SCP).

However, a [corollary article](http://www.scp-wiki.net/experiment-log-t-98816-oc108-682) to [SCP-682](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-682) includes a list of experiments designed to destroy SCP-682.  One of the experiments pits SCP-682 against SCP-173.  While the account of the experiment isn't extremely detailed, I think it at leaves gives the general impression that SCP-173 is tougher than mere concrete.

Answer (score 7):

As KHW says, it's highly unlikely that there is (or ever will be) a canon answer to your question.

The [SCP (Secure, Contain, Protect) website](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-173) contains a series of single page [Flash-Fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_fiction) stories, usually with some kind of photo-manipulated picture as an illustration. Although some of the "inmates" and objects contained within *are* the subject of [fan-fiction](http://www.scp-wiki.net/foundation-tales), these short stories rarely give much insight into the precise characteristics, tending more towards short horror fiction.

As far as your question goes, the in-universe description indicates that it is made of

> "concrete and rebar with traces of Krylon brand spray paint"

which would seem to indicate that it is susceptible to physical damage.

Out of universe, the statue (which inspired the creation of the SCP website) was originally made by sculptor Izumi Kato. It is called "[Untitled](http://www.scaithebathhouse.com/en/exhibitions/2005/04/izumi_kato/)" and is constructed of wood, charcoal and acrylic rather than concrete.

Comment: I think the more general term "microfiction" is appropriate. Drabbles are exactly 100 words, and all SCP entries are much longer than that.

Comment: You're right, of course. I was using it in a semi-pejorative sense to indicate *any* form of short fiction.

Comment: [There actually *are* stories](http://www.scp-wiki.net/foundation-tales) on the SCP website (outside of the actual entries), many of which feature the 'inmates'. However, few of them offer any greater explanation of the SCPs they feature, and this is doubly true of the first few SCPs, which are held in a sort of state of reverence.

Comment: Cheerfully edited to include a link to the stories section. Let me know if there's any stories that include SCP-173 and I'll add any salient info to my answer.