# How does SCP-173 generate feces?

Tags: scp-foundation

[SCP-173](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-173) is meant to be made of concrete, but what's strange is that it creates blood and feces. How would something like that generate blood and feces?

I know it can move when not looked at, so does it have some sort of pocket dimension and can't teleport when looked at?

[image: SCP-173, an extremely tall concrete creature in the corner of a cell with its body facing the wall and the head tilted towards the viewer, a red arrow points at the brown/red stained floor]

Comment: what exactly is it that you are asking?

Comment: Related - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43509/is-scp-173-just-as-vulnerable-as-normal-concrete-or-less

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more clear what you're actually asking (as well as providing a link to those of us who can't remember every SCP off-hand). Feel free to make further edits to clarify, or undo what I've done if you think I went too far

Comment: I am guessing the question is ultimately "Why can't crowd-sourced scenarios be internally consistent?" or alternately "Why am I asking this here instead of on a scp-wiki.net forum?"

Comment: A wizard did it.

Comment: @infixed: Although SCP is a wiki, its individual pages are generally owned by their authors in much the same way as individual Stack Exchange questions and answers are owned.  SCP-173 has largely been written by a single person, with minimal formatting and metadata changes introduced by others.  Some attempted additions were reverted by the site's moderators because they materially altered the content of the page.  It cannot be reasonably characterized as "crowd-sourced."

Comment: @Adamant no, I didn't. ;)

Answer (score 7):

It clearly states in [the description](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-173) that

> The reddish brown substance on the floor is a combination of feces and
>   blood. **Origin of these materials is unknown.**

So there you go. It's unknown.